# running multiline bash command over ssh does not work

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to run a multi-line bash command over ssh, all possible attempt exhausted but no luck --

```
echo "3. All files found, creating remote directory on the server."
ssh -t $id@$host bash -c "'
                if [[ -d ~/_tmp ]]; then
                    rm -rf ~/_tmp/*
                else
                    mkdir ~/_tmp
                fi
'" ;

echo "4. Sending files ..."
scp ${files[@]} $id@$host:~/_tmp/ ;
```

Here is the output --

```
user@linux:/tmp$ ./remotecompile
1. Please enter your id:
user
2. Please enter the names of the files that you want to compile
   (Filenames *must* be space separated):
test.txt
3. All files found, creating remote directory on the server.
Password: 
Unmatched '.
Unmatched '.
Connection to host.domain.com closed.
```

Please note, I do not want to put every 2-3 lines of bash if-then-else-fi commands into separate files.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: By the way, you need to quote more on your SCP command: `scp "${files[@]}" "$id@$host:~/_tmp/"` -- unquoted, `${files[@]}` behaves precisely the same as `${files[*]}`, with all the bugs associated with same.

Comment: Viewed 2k times and I'm the first upvote? This is why we have that little banner that says "don't forget to upvote", people. Srsly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an escaped heredoc to have its literal contents passed through. (Without the escaping, ie. using just `<<EOF`, shell expansions would be processed locally -- making for more interesting corner cases if you used variables inside your remotely-run code).

```sh
ssh "$id@$host" bash <<'EOF'
if [[ -d ~/_tmp ]]; then
    rm -rf ~/_tmp/*
else
    mkdir ~/_tmp
fi
EOF
```

If you want to pass arguments, doing so in an unambiguously correct manner gets more interesting (since there are two separate layers of shell parsing involved), but the `printf '%q'` builtin saves the day:

```
args=( "this is" "an array" "of things to pass" \
       "this next one is a literal asterisk" '*' )
printf -v args_str '%q ' "${args[@]}"
ssh "$id@$host" bash -s "$args_str" <<'EOF'
  echo "Demonstrating local argument processing:"
  printf '%q\n' "$@"
  echo "The asterisk is $5"
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
ssh [hostname] '       
if [[ -d ~/_tmp ]]; then
   rm -rf ~/_tmp
else
   mkdir ~/_tmp
fi
'
```

Comment: I agree that this works fine in the case here. When the code to run remotely includes its own single-quotes, on the other hand, it gets unwieldy.

Comment: there is another problem, for every ssh/scp I need to put password every time, is there any way I can avoid it?

Comment: @ramgorur, ControlMaster is your friend in that case, if you don't want to do the Right Thing and use RSA authentication.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, what is a ControlMaster? could you please give me some point?

Comment: Google will have lots of hits for "ssh controlmaster". You should also have no trouble finding questions and answer on-topic on ServerFault (which, unlike StackOverflow, is the right place for questions about system administration tools).